# AngularJS bootstrap methodology

Tags: angularjs, grails

I'm trying to manage the bootstrap process of a large AngularJS/Grails application. Here's what I've come up with, but I'm not so sure it's as clean as it could be, or as efficient. Thoughts?

1. Load angular-loader in a one-line minified /script
2. Load jquery explicity in another /script
3. Load a third-party async loader ($script) and all of the remaining dependencies
4. When the dependencies have loaded, call `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp]);`
5. Load my minified, concatenated app-specific javascript in another /script

This seems clunky. What alternatives might there be? I did consider RequireJS, but I don't like how intrusive it is, and I like using a grunt task to concat+uglify my app into a single script.

Comment: I have limited knowledge of Grails but I understand that you want Grails to take care of gathering the dependencies. Where do you intend to call angular.bootstrap from?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken [this video](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/groovy-grails/grails-for-hipsters) talks about Grails and Angular integration.

Comment: Do you have the opportunity to use tools like grunt? I can recommend a nice build process if you do.

Comment: I decided to go with a Grunt solution wherein I manually load `<script> jquery, angular, app.min.js`. App.min.js is a concatenated file of all my angular code. Not beautiful, but a lot cleaner than most alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach that I use is to load the basic components upfront and only load the controller and associated services on demand using RequireJS.  Obviously, this is only applicable if you are dealing with large application.

As AngularJS does not natively support on-demand loading and delegate such task to async loader such as RequireJS, I encapsulated the logic need in something I call `angularAMD`.

Here is a sample site I created to illustrate how `angularAMD` works:

http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/